# How can I inherit class in C++?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

I have used this code to inherit class A with class B.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

class A {
    int a,b,c;
    public:
    A(int x, int y, int z) {
      a=x;
      b=y;
      c=z;
    }
    void honk() {
      a+=5;
      b+=5;
      c+=5;
    }
 };


class B: public A {
  public:
      int p;

};

int main() {
    A ob1(10, 12, 13);

  B obj;
  obj.honk();
  cout << A.a + " " + A.b + " " + A.c;
  return 0;
}
```

This is giving a error **Error: no matching function for call to A::A()**

How can I solve this? TIA.

Comment: The line `cout << A.a + " " + A.b + " " + A.c;` will also give error.

Answer (score 2):

`class A` does not have a default constructor defined. You only have the `A(int x, int y, int z)` defined. For example the following would fail:

```
A myvar; // declaration with default constructor (which doesn't exist)
```

But this would be OK:

```
A myvar(1, 2, 3);
```

When `B` constructs `A`, it's the same situation. `B` needs to use a valid `A` constructor during its initialization.

Here are some solutions:

```
class B: public A {
  public:
      // 1. This forwards constructor arguments from B to A.
      B(int x, int y, int z) :
          A(x, y, z)
      {
      }

      // 2. This conforms to your example;
      //    default constructor of B passes
      //    its own arguments to A
      B() :
          A(1, 2, 3)
      {
      }

      int p;

};
```

Comment: `B obj;` will cause error with this code.

Comment: I want to add 5 to the variables of object of class A. but its adding 5 to the variables of class B object